# Face rotation results with deformation in modifier stack

Tags: modeling, modifiers, transforms

I try to rotate a face, but the original form is deformed. Please view attached blend file for more details.

[image]
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuAcyL2kNiCPg7l0Vk7C-Vl4Bo0FKg?e=LdeKBM

Answer (score 2):

Your issue comes from Scale transformation that is set to x=5 y=3 z=1 now.

[image]

To fix the issue go to **Object > Apply** and choose **Scale**...

[image]

... scale transformation become to x=1 y=1 z=1 ... issue is gone. For more info see [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#apply).

[image]

Quite important is to understand transformation hierarchy. Modifiers are calculated first, object transforms after that. It means your Solidify modifier extrudes a thickness and after that is calculated Scale transformation on object. Since your object is scaled x=5 y=3 z=1, result is squeezed object.

It's always recommended to Apply Transformations to an object before using modifiers and armatures to avoid strange behaviour.

If you will have a default plane (dimension 2x2), you scaled to 2 (= dimension 4x4), than you add Solidify modifier with Thickness set to 1m ... object appears in a scene with "Dimension" 4x4x2 and not 1, because modifier is calculated before object transformation (like Scale) setup.

Comment: if the answer solved your issue, consider click a check mark next to the answer, so others with similar issue can see it was solved (easier from a list of Question).

Comment: i first time try Blender. can you give me step by step.

Comment: I adjust my answer. Object transform info (like Scale) you can find in 3D editor > Properties (Side) panel (N) or in Properties editor > Object label.

Comment: Thank. I did it. Happy weekend vklidu